# How to select which variables to drop using aggregate function in r

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am using the `aggregate` function in R to aggregate data together. I want it to drop some levels but keep other levels.

For example, I'm working with data that looks like this:

```
  Donor Recipient value  location time
1    d1        r1     2        in 2000
2    d2        r2     3       out 2002
3    d3        r3     4        in 2004
4    d4        r1     5       out 2000
5    d5        r2     1 undefined 2002
6    d6        r3     3       out 2004
7    d6        r1     4        in 2002
```

I want to aggregate the `value` column.

Specifically, I want to keep all the levels in the `location` column and drop all the unused levels in the `time` column. Such that even for the `Recipient` who do not have all three possible levels (i.e. `in, out, or undefined`), still get assigned all three levels in the aggregation. However, I do not want the `Recipient` to get assigned each level in `time` column. I only want them to keep their assigned the year.

I want the data to look like this:

```
  Recipient  location time value
        r1        in 2000     2
        r1       out 2000     5
        r1 undefined 2000     NA
        r1        in 2002     4
        r1       out 2002     NA
        r1 undefined 2002     NA
        r2        in 2002     NA
        r2       out 2002     3
        r2 undefined 2002     1
        r3        in 2004     4
        r3       out 2004     3
        r3 undefined 2004     NA
```

**What I have tried**

First, I use the following formula. It keeps the assigned `time` column but does not assign each `location` factor to each `Recipient`.

```
aggregate(value  ~ Recipient + location + time, data = df, sum)

  Recipient  location time value
1        r1        in 2000     2
2        r1       out 2000     5
3        r1        in 2002     4
4        r2       out 2002     3
5        r2 undefined 2002     1
6        r3        in 2004     4
7        r3       out 2004     3
```

Second, I use the `drop = F` argument in the `aggregate` function. This gives me each of the `location` levels, which is what I want. But It assigned all the `time` levels, which is what I do not want.

```
aggregate(value  ~ Recipient + location + time, data = df, sum, drop = F)

   Recipient  location time value
1         r1        in 2000     2
2         r2        in 2000    NA
3         r3        in 2000    NA
4         r1       out 2000     5
5         r2       out 2000    NA
6         r3       out 2000    NA
7         r1 undefined 2000    NA
8         r2 undefined 2000    NA
9         r3 undefined 2000    NA
10        r1        in 2002     4
11        r2        in 2002    NA
12        r3        in 2002    NA
13        r1       out 2002    NA
14        r2       out 2002     3
15        r3       out 2002    NA
16        r1 undefined 2002    NA
17        r2 undefined 2002     1
18        r3 undefined 2002    NA
19        r1        in 2004    NA
20        r2        in 2004    NA
21        r3        in 2004     4
22        r1       out 2004    NA
23        r2       out 2004    NA
24        r3       out 2004     3
25        r1 undefined 2004    NA
26        r2 undefined 2004    NA
27        r3 undefined 2004    NA
```

Lastly, when I remove the year, it works as I want it to: assigning each `location` factor to each `Recipient`. But, I need to hold the `time` constant as part of the aggregation

```
aggregate(value  ~ Recipient + location, data = df, sum, drop = F)

  Recipient  location value
1        r1        in     6
2        r2        in    NA
3        r3        in     4
4        r1       out     5
5        r2       out     3
6        r3       out     3
7        r1 undefined    NA
8        r2 undefined     1
9        r3 undefined    NA
```

From here, I'm left with two solutions: 1. loop through all the years individually or 2. paste the year to the `Recipient` and extract it after the aggregation. Both of these options are clunky.

Is there a way to get the aggregate function to produce the data structure I need?

**Replication data**

```
Donor <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d6")
Recipient <- c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r1")
time <-c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2002)
value <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4)
location <- c("in", "out", "in", "out", "undefined", "out", "in")

df <- data.frame(Donor, Recipient, value, location, time)
```

**Updated Replication Data for Aggregating**

```
Donor <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d6", "d7")
Recipient <- c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r1", "r1")
time <-c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2002, 2002)
value <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4)
location <- c("in", "out", "in", "out", "undefined", "out", "in", "in")

df <- data.frame(Donor, Recipient, value, location, time)

  Donor Recipient value  location time
1    d1        r1     2        in 2000
2    d2        r2     3       out 2002
3    d3        r3     4        in 2004
4    d4        r1     5       out 2000
5    d5        r2     1 undefined 2002
6    d6        r3     3       out 2004
7    d6        r1     4        in 2002
8    d7        r1     4        in 2002
```

Note: rows 7 and 8 need to be aggregated.

*Expected Output For Updated Data*

```
   Recipient time  location value
1         r1 2000        in     2
2         r1 2000       out     5
3         r1 2000 undefined    NA
4         r1 2002        in     8
5         r1 2002       out    NA
6         r1 2002 undefined    NA
7         r2 2002        in    NA
8         r2 2002       out     3
9         r2 2002 undefined     1
10        r3 2004        in     4
11        r3 2004       out     3
12        r3 2004 undefined    NA
```

Comment: aggregate is the wrong term to use here. Seems like you want to show the value for all possible combinations of recipient, location, and time based only on the values that occur in the data and replacing those that don't occur with NA.

Comment: This is correct. However, My example data does not accurately, reflect my problem. I have updated the question to reflect the data I'm using more closely.

Comment: What is your expected output for the updated data?

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the expected output for updated data. Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Then aggregate first, and then use Ronak's solution.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give that a try! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(-Donor) %>%
  group_by(Recipient, time) %>%
  tidyr::complete(location = unique(df$location))

#   Recipient  time location  value
#   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 r1         2000 in            2
# 2 r1         2000 out           5
# 3 r1         2000 undefined    NA
# 4 r1         2002 in            4
# 5 r1         2002 out          NA
# 6 r1         2002 undefined    NA
# 7 r2         2002 in           NA
# 8 r2         2002 out           3
# 9 r2         2002 undefined     1
#10 r3         2004 in            4
#11 r3         2004 out           3
#12 r3         2004 undefined    NA
```

Comment: This will aggregate the value column, as well? Also, do I have to select away all the columns I do not want? I ask because I'm using this on a much larger data frame.

Comment: I don't think `aggregate` is the right term here. We are expanding the data to include all the incomplete `location` values for each `Recipient` and `time`. You can keep the columns which you don't want, those will generate `NA` same as `value` column.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Expanding the data isn't going to help me in this situation. I need a function that can aggregate the data while, at the same time, preserving the ```location``` levels for all ```Recipient```

Comment: @SharifAmlani Your original data has 7 rows, your expected output has 12 rows. What is that called? Did you try the answer?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Nevertheless, my issue remains constant. Say I add an 8th row that I need to aggregate with its counterpart. Expanding the data using your function will not be successful. I'm sorry, it's my fault. I provided a poor example dataframe that did not accurately reflect my problem. This one is representative: ```Donor <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d6", "d7")
Recipient <- c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r1", "r1")
time <-c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2002, 2002)
value <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4)
location <- c("in", "out", "in", "out", "undefined", "out", "in", "in")```